# How do I know which mold agent is best?

Tags: mold

I've had several mold remediation specialists come to my home each touting their preferred EPA approved mold killing agent including: Cal-brite, Fiberlock Shockwave, Microban BotaniClean. I've looked at the specs and can't tell the difference. Their prices very greatly. How do I know which one to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, read through the [EPA site on mold](http://www.epa.gov/mold/moldguide.html).

If you look carefully, you will not find an EPA **recommended** product.

Spores can be removed with detergent and water.  Spores can be killed with bleach and other disinfectants (biocides), but the EPA says:

> The use of a chemical or biocide that kills organisms such as mold (chlorine bleach, for example) is 
>   not recommended as a routine practice during mold cleanup.

More importantly, is the source of moisture under control?  Have all wet areas been exposed and dried out.

Once the interior framing is dried out to 10 to 12%, (consider buying a non-contact moisture meter and insist the framing be dried out before continuing), you can spray seal your framing with a primer to encapsulate any remaining spores and close the walls.

Answer (score 0):

I am a mold remediation specialist and I will give you some advice:

1. Go to their website. If they are serious they will invest in it.
2. Google their company name. Do they have social media profiles?
3. Try to find their recommendations.
4. Call them and ask for certificates.